# Why does the expression get printed along with the curly braces?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

The code is supposed to print the first element in the todo app which is "Build a Todo App". It also does not include the new elements which I am adding into the app.

I have proceeded according to a tutorial and the code is exactly the same. I have cross checked it many times but my app still displays `{{todo.title}}` instead of "Build a Todo app"

My code:

```
    <style>
        .done{text-decoration: line-through; color:#ccc;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div ng-controller="todoController">
        <form name="frm" ng-submit="addTodo()">
        <input type="text" name="newtodo" ng-model="newTodo" required />
        <button ng-disabled="frm.$invalid" ng-click="addtodo()">Add</button>
        </form>
        <button ng-click="clearCompleted()">Clear Completed</button>
        <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done" />
                    <span ng-class="{'done':todo.done}">{{todo.title}}</span>

                </li>
        </ul>

    </div>


        <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            angular.module('ToDo', [])
            ToDo.controller('todoController',['$scope', function($scope){

                $scope.todos = [
                    {'title': 'Build a ToDo App', 'done': false}
                ];
                $scope.addtodo = function(){

                    $scope.todos.push({'title': $scope.newTodo , 'done': false})
                    $scope.newTodo=' '
                }
                $scope.clearCompleted = function(){
                    $scope.todos = $scope.todos.filter(function(item){
                        return !item.done
                    })
                }
            }])
        </script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please share this code on a Plunkr or some place?

Comment: Perhaps you are not even initiating the code by mentioning `ng-app`. This will be clear only if you add full code for us to debug.

Answer (score 0):

So, It seems there was some residual code from elsewhere. I've cleared that up.

```js
let ToDo = angular.module('myApp', [])
    ToDo.controller('todoController',['$scope', function($scope){

                $scope.todos = [
                    {'title': 'Build a ToDo App', 'done': false}
                ];
                $scope.addtodo = function(){

                    $scope.todos.push({'title': $scope.newTodo , 'done': false})
                    $scope.newTodo=' '
                }
                $scope.clearCompleted = function(){
                    $scope.todos = $scope.todos.filter(function(item){
                        return !item.done
                    })
                }
            }])
```

```css
          .done{text-decoration: line-through; color:#ccc;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="todoController">
        <form name="frm" ng-submit="addTodo()">
        <input type="text" name="newtodo" ng-model="newTodo" required />
        <button ng-disabled="frm.$invalid" ng-click="addtodo()">Add</button>
        </form>
        <button ng-click="clearCompleted()">Clear Completed</button>
        <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done" />
                    <span ng-class="{'done':todo.done}">{{todo.title}}</span>

                </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</body>


</html>
```

> What was wrong?

- There was no ToDo variable. Added  `let ToDo`
- The controller name was different from the one in the HTML
- The module was named ToDo instead of myApp as in the HTML
- Added `ng-app` to the body